# tfs extension Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: ajax, rest, tfs, cross-domain, teamcity

I encounter a problem when I try to call the Teamcity REST service through a TFS extension.

I configured TeamCity as well:
rest.cors.origins = "http://my.tfsserver"
rest.cors.optionsRequest.allowUnauthorized = true

In the TFS extension, I call the following url:
http: //my.teamcity.server:80/app/rest/latest/projects using "XMLHttpRequest"

```
   const pair :string=this.settings.username+":"+this.settings.password;      
   const encodedCreds:string = btoa(pair);
   const basicAuthValue:string = "Basic "+ encodedCreds;       

    const apiurl:string="/app/rest/latest/projects";
    const completeUrl:string = this.settings.urlTeamCity+apiurl;       

    const  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",completeUrl,true);        

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', basicAuthValue);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ,"http://my.tfsserver");
    xhr.onload=function(){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    xhr.onerror=function(){
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
    xhr.send();
```

I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Failed to load http://my.teamcity.server:80/app/rest/latest/projects:
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

In the TeamCity rest log, i have the following two lines:

> [2018-10-01 14:12:49,891]  DEBUG [p-nio-80-exec-9] -
>   er.rest.APIController/rest-api - Got CORS request from origin 'null',
>   but this origin is not allowed. Add the origin to 'rest.cors.origins'
>   internal property (comma-separated) to trust the applications hosted
>   on the domain. Current allowed origins are: Enabled CORS Origins:
>   [http://my.tfsserver]
>
> [2018-10-01 14:12:49,892]  DEBUG [p-nio-80-exec-9] -
>   er.rest.APIController/rest-api - REST API request processing finished
>   in 1ms, status code: 302, request: OPTIONS
>   '/app/rest/latest/projects', from client 10.69.152.71:59256, no auth

Based on the last line, i modify my code to:

```
...
   xhr.open("GET",completeUrl,true,this.settings.username,this.settings.password)
   xhr.withCredentials=true;
...
```

but, i'm still getting the same error in both chrome console and team city rest log.

in the chrome console, on the network tab, i can see that "origin" header is null but i don't understand why?

[image]

Thanks by adavance for any help :)